# Label and ticks using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using `pgfplots` to plot simple functions. For example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=0.5]
\addplot[color=black] coordinates {
(0,0.2)
(0.5,0.2)
(1,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to add a letter, say "x", at the point 0.5 on the horizontal axis to make some emphasis. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Do you just want the letter "x", or do you also want to draw a vertical line or something like that? Should the letter be aligned like the tick numbers, or should it be inside the axis?

Comment: @Jake I think it would be better to put the letter inside the axis, because sometimes this emphasis might coincide with the original labels.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `extra ...` options:

```
extra x ticks={0.5},
extra x tick labels={$x$},
```

[image]

### Notes:

- As per  Qrrbrbirlbel's suggestion, the `extra` tick labels are now aligned with the other labels.
- As requested in the comments I have added multiple `extra` tick marks.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=0.5,
  extra x ticks={0.1,0.5,0.7},
  extra x tick labels={$x$,$y$,$z$},
  extra x tick style={%
     text height=\heightof{0},% Align labels at baseline
     color=red,
  },
]
\addplot[color=black] coordinates {
  (0,0.2)
  (0.5,0.2)
  (1,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we align the `x` to the baselines from the other ticks? `extra x tick style={text height=\heightof{0}}` is one way, but not very nice.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks a lot. But if I want to add two or more labels, I tried that extra x ticks={0.1,0.5,0.7}, extra x tick labels={$x$,$y$,$z$} does not work. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Good point, but I was not able to find another way to do that.

Comment: @Richie: Have updated solution to show that it can be extended to multiple labels. Perhaps you are using an older release.  I am using the latest version in TeXLive2012.

Comment: @LeonMeier Did you try with `height("0")`?

Comment: @LeonMeier: No, it's a new syntax. It's explained in pages 937 and 938 from `pgfmanual.pdf`. `height("0")` gives you the height of whatever is inside quotes. Similar functions are `depth` and `width`.